# Redirecting to correct page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the same

```
@Html.ActionLink("SUSPEND", "Suspend", "Serials", new { id = s.serial, orderId = s.Order.orderID }, null)
```

on two different pages.

Let's say I can click on it from this page:

```
http://localhost:55058/Customers/Details/4106
```

and from this page:

```
http://localhost:55058/Orders/Details/102091
```

How do I `Redirect()` to the page *where I clicked*, once the action is completed? *Possibly, in an elegant way...*

Thanks.

Comment: have you got your controller to hand? rather than return **view** you can return **redirectToAction** method

Comment: I think OP means to redirect to the source of where the actionlink was clicked? I could be wrong though.

Comment: I have slightly improved the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to do this:

```
var url = Request.UrlReferrer;

if(url != null)
  return Redirect(url.ToString());
```